Ubuntu 24.04 - 100% gnome-shell usage - how to diagnose?
I have upgraded my (single-core) laptop to Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS, and whilst it runs almost perfectly, the current version of gnome-shell (46.0-0ubuntu6~24.04.4) has spikes where it reaches 100% of CPU, leaving the GUI unable to be woken up when the screen is off. I can log in remotely and the command line works well from there, so I can terminate the process.
How can I diagnose why this is occurring? I have no extensions running, and those which were installed have been updated to the latest versions.
EDIT: It's a HP 15-db0598sa 15.6" Laptop with AMD A6-9225 processor, 8GB memory, AMD Radeon R4 Graphics and Realtek RTL8723DE wi-fi adaptor.

Please [edit] your question and give more info about your hardware.

I have the same problem.  I updated from 22.04 to 24.04 and it began.  I will walk away from the computer and at random times, when I come back the ui will be non-responsive.  So, it must happen before the screen lock is supposed to kick in at 15 minutes.  It also happens when the screen is locked.   I can also get into it remotely and kill it, but anything that I have been working on will be gone of course.
I have a newer HP Pavilion Desktop TP01-3xxx
Product number: 318K3AA#ABA
System board ID: 89B5
CPU: 12th gen intel i5-12400
Ram: 12GB
